# Python: AttributeError: x node has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python, attributeerror

This is another question in vein of my previous one about a project.

I have read some other (answered) questions related to this, but I did not understand the answers much at all, and am hoping to get better understanding.

I am attempting to implement a simplified version of a larger program that I am working on for a project. The issue I am encountering is that it's giving me an error I don't understand, it is more confusing because the code I use for declaring the class is pulled directly from the 'full' code where it works fine.

The declaration of a new class is here. It is working in another program.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.farmer, self.wolf, self.sheep, self.cabbage = False, False, False, False
        self.parent = None
        self.cost = 0
```

But when I attempt to use it with this code:

```
parent = node
fchild = node
schild = node
wchild = node
cchild = node

fchild = parent
fchild.farmer != fchild.farmer
fchild.parent = parent
fchild.cost += 1
```

The result is an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boolfliptest.py", line 17, in <module>
    fchild.farmer != fchild.farmer
AttributeError: class node has no attribute 'farmer'
```

As I said, I have seen other questions about this topic, but I did not understand the answers, and I am further confused because it works on the other program. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing here? Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 5):

The [`__init__`](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-init.html) method of a class (commonly called the "constructor" method) is only called when you create a new instance of the class.  Furthermore, all of the attributes you are trying to access are contained in the `__init__` method.  This means that they are instance attributes and will only be available *after* you create an instance of the class.

So, to fix your problem, make those variables point to instances of the class:

```
# By adding (), I initialize (create an instance of) class node.
# This means that I will be calling the __init__ method.
parent = node()
fchild = node()
schild = node()
wchild = node()
cchild = node()
```

As it currently stands, your code is simply assigning those variables to the class itself, not instances of it.

Comment: Ha, that seems like an obvious mistake. Thanks for the information, I'll be more careful with my variables next time.

Comment: @user2828965 - Glad to help!  Don't forget to accept my answer (click the tick) if it solved your problem appropriately.